# Openethereum/parity import export

Tags: import, export

anyone has used export to take a backup and import to load data in openethereum(parity) blockchain? please provide information

- I have tried export .rlp file and it works but when trying to import that .rlp file and want my block chain to to start syncing from next block that is not working is there anyone who has done something similar please help